# Putting StackOverflow or LinkedIn URLs in Resume/CV

Tags: interviewing, job-search, linkedin, business-cards

I observed that many recruitment agents are stripping *Stackoverflow*, *LinkedIn* information and other contact information from candidates' CVs to prevent employers from directly contacting the candidates.

Also, Agents are not accepting PDF versions of CVs as they cannot modify it.

What is the best way to let the employers see your *StackOverflow* or *LinkedIn* profiles with ease?

Is it wise to print *SO* and *LinkedIn* info on Business cards and share it during an interview?

Any other suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 7):

> What is the best way to let the employers see your StackOverflow or LinkedIn profiles with ease ?

Don't use a recruiter, or find one that will allow it.  I'm not trying to be snarky here; it just seems like the only solution.

I don't have much experience with recruiters.  However, my understanding is that at least some of them have close working relationships with the companies for whom they are doing the recruiting, and wouldn't be afraid of companies making an end run around them.  So I don't think it would be an issue for everybody. If this is important to you, then make that clear to the recruiter, and don't work with them if they insist it must be removed.

> Is it wise to print SO and LinkedIn info on Business card and share it with interview during the interview ?

I don't think this is so helpful.  *Before you get to interview* is the time when this information would be most valuable. A resume is basically a tool to get you to the interview.  Once you are there, the impression you make face to face is most important.

Comment: I don't understand how removing my contact information would revert the company from contacting me directly. It's more of an unwritten code - if the whole interview goes through a recruiter or an agency, all parties keep it this way to the very end. Pure decency.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a personal website, can you maybe put your site URL on there and relevant links? But again, if recruiters are sending amended versions of your CV, then it's likely this will happen again.

Unfortunately, in some instances you have to use recruiters and they have to protect their interests (as this is how they get paid).

Answer (score 0):

> Is it wise to print SO and LinkedIn info on Business cards and share
>   it during an interview?

Instead of printing your own card which might look a little bit awkward. Print your own CV that includes your social media accounts and pass it to the interviewer.

Comment: While you are not wrong, this doesn't answer what OP is asking. OP is applying for jobs through a recruiter, not directly. OP doesn't have a say in what the recruiter is showing the company (in other words, as explained, URL's might've been stripped).

Comment: but you don't meet with the agent for the interview, do you? In another words, you pass your CV to the hiring manager or the interviewer who is a recruitment agent.

Comment: You don't meet with the agent for the interview, no. You do meet with a corporate recruiter, though. In my experience, corporate recruiters and hiring managers take your resumé as-is, while third-party recruiters might edit your resumé to make you more appealing. Thus OP is wondering whether it's a good idea to provide stuff like links to SO/Github/LI in case it would be stripped off the resumé.

Answer (score -1):

I would not personally be comfortable putting my profile from any site in my resume but if you want to do it, you can have a personal copy of your resume in any format and include information you want. You can use that resume to apply online directly on company's website and also to hand it out to interviewer during the interview.

> Is it wise to print SO and LinkedIn info on Business card

You obviously will not give out your current company's business card in a job interview and I do not think it is worth to print a personal business card just for this purpose. If you have reached the interview site, then they have all the information to find you on linkedin/SO anyway.

Comment: If you're very active on SO or contribute to open source projects on Github, it's very wise to include that in a manner that people can check.

Comment: Got it. Hence I said "I would not" because none of my profiles are worth sharing!